# How to access my mac or pc from my iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, vnc

I have to access mac or windows pc from my iPhone. Can any one tell which frameworks or which concepts i have to use to get this.

Thank you

Comment: In iTunes AppStore, search for VNC.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the word "framework" I am assuming this actually is a programming question, so I won't vote to close.

If you want to send data to and from a PC or Mac, you do it via a Wi-Fi network. You (probably, depending on what you want to do exactly) need to create a desktop app running that implements Bonjour, then it can talk to the the iPhone.

Take a look at the [Net Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html) on how to do this.

Comment: Yes this programming question. Actually in my project i want to remotely access my MAC in iPhone. For this what i have to use, i am not much experienced iPhone Developer so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

VNC... Mocha VNC will work straight off with your mac, and if you download UltraVNC server for your Windows PC that will work too.

Not really programming related...

Answer (score 0):

logmein ignition is available from the app store if you already use logmein. It works, though it's a little clumsy due to no real mouse being available.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used bonjour for inner-network communication between applications (that's probably the preferred way on the Apple platform, as mentioned above by @bpapa), but you can use Sockets and Streams to communicate and transfer data between applications on the same network.  Here's the link for the apple reference guide:

[Mac Dev Center: Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html)

EDIT: Sorry, the above implies that sockets only work on the same network - this is not true.  To be specific, inner-network is the easiest type of communication because some things (like UDP packets) are dropped at internet borders (routers, switches, etc).  With inter-network communication, you also have to worry about having access to the appropriate ports on both networks as well.